# Why is $12$ the smallest value of $m$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

In our advanced algebra course, we just learned about the notion of the *conductor* of certain abelian extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. In the specific example I had in mind, the conductor is simply the smallest value of $m$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$. It turns out that this is equal to the discrimant of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, which, by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant_of_an_algebraic_number_field, is equal to $12$.

But, I'm wondering how one can rigorously show that this really is the smallest such desired value. I understand that, using one of the elementary cases that motivated Kronecker-Weber Theorem, $\sqrt{3}$ can be written as a sum of two powers of primitive $12$th roots of unity, since $\sqrt{3} = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{12}} - e^{\frac{10 \pi i}{12}}$. But I don't understand why $12$ is the smallest value $m$ such that we can write $\sqrt{3}$ as a sum of powers of $m$th roots of unity. Is there a robust way to show this ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just look at the quadratic subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m), m\leq 11$, and see that none of them are equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. This would be the quickest way. To sepped up the process, you could use ramification theory: $3$ will ramify (because it already in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, and it is known that it implies $3\mid m$. So you would have 3 values left to check: $m=3,6,9$ and $m=3$ .In any case, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is the only quadratic subfield, which cannot contain $\sqrt{3}$ since its intersection with the reals is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: To write @GreginGre ‘s first suggested solution. The Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is $G_n=(\mathbb{Z}/(n))^{\times}$, and the complex conjugation is $-1$. Thus real quadratic subfields correspond to subgroups of index $2$ containing $-1$. If $G_n$ is cyclic, then there is only one subgroup of index $2$, that of squares. If it contains $-1$, then $-1$ is a square mod $n$. This prevents all $n < 12$ except $n=5$ (or $10$ but the two fields are the same). But $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ already contains $\sqrt{5}$: if it contained $\sqrt{3}$, it would have been totally real, a contradiction.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks for the comment! However, the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{12})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not cyclic-- so how does the argument still follow ?

Comment: The argument shows that, for $n < 12$, $\sqrt{3} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ (in particular because the Galois groups are cyclic). I’m not dealing with the case $n=12$.